# Get KeyboardAvoidingView to work when using `Dimensions.get('window').height` to set a MapView

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am using MapView to display a Map (filling most of the screen).

The intent is that my users can specify a location by:

1. Dragging a Marker on the map (From which we use the lat/long)
2. Input a Location name using a TextInput

**Problem:**

The TextInput is at the bottom of the screen, and whenever the keyboard is active, this covers up the TextInput. I have used KeyboardAvoidView, but it's not doing the trick.

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
      behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
      style={{marginTop: '1%'}}
    > 
        <MapView
            style={[AppStyles.map]}
            initialRegion={{
            latitude: coords.latitude,
            longitude: coords.longitude,
            latitudeDelta: 0.4822,
            longitudeDelta: 0.3221,
            }}
        >
            <Marker 
                draggable
                coordinate={coords}
                onDrag={(e) => {setCoords(e.nativeEvent.coordinate)}}
                onDragEnd={(e) => setCoords(e.nativeEvent.coordinate)}
            />

        </MapView>
        <View style={[AppStyles.container, AppStyles.mapViewContainer]}>      
        <TextInput 
            style={[AppStyles.input]}
            onChangeText={(text) => setLocationName(text)}
            placeholder="Name of Location"
        />
            <TouchableOpacity style={[AppStyles.buttonBlue, AppStyles.section, AppStyles.buttonBlueSmall]} onPress={() => {addLocation}}>
              <Text style={AppStyles.locationButtonText}>Add</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

This styling code may be relevant too:

```
  map: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height - 200,
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I solved this by adding Keyboard listeners, that fire events when keyword is open/closed. Using this I get the height of the keyboard, and I set a
`shortHeight` for my `MapView` to use when Keyboard is active.

```
const [shortHeight, setShortHeight] = useState(0);
const [width, setWidth] = useState(Dimensions.get('window').width);

useEffect(() => {
    const showSubscription = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', (e) => {
      setKeyboardStatus(true);
      onKeyboardDidShow(e);
    });
    const hideSubscription = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', () => {
      setKeyboardStatus(false);
    });
    console.log(shortHeight)
    return () => {
        showSubscription.remove();
        hideSubscription.remove();
    }
}, []);
```

And then adjusting my MapView height on the basis of the shortHeight set above.

```
<MapView
            style={!keyboardStatus ? AppStyles.map : {width: width, height: shortHeight}}
            initialRegion={{
            latitude: coords.latitude,
            longitude: coords.longitude,
            latitudeDelta: 0.4822,
            longitudeDelta: 0.3221,
            }}
        >
            <Marker 
                draggable
                coordinate={coords}
                onDrag={(e) => {setCoords(e.nativeEvent.coordinate)}}
                onDragEnd={(e) => setCoords(e.nativeEvent.coordinate)}
            />

        </MapView>
```